# A specified library is missing

Tags: theming

On a custom theme "foobar" (based on Olivero) this error message occured.
This custom theme is a copy of drupals 9.2.2 olivero's theme.

> Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\InvalidLibrariesExtendSpecificationException:
> The specified library "foobar/cke-dialog" does not exist. in
> Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->applyLibrariesExtend()
> (line 154 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryCollector.php).

My custom theme lives in `web/themes/custom/foobar` in `foobar.libraries.yml` I have defined the library:

```yml
cke-dialog:
  css:
    component:
      css/components/cke-dialog.css: {}
```

I did **cleared all cache** and the path to the library is correct.

I don't see what I'm missing here

Comment: If the YML is verbatim you have an indentation error (`component` needs another space before it), but that's probably not causing that error as you'd expect to see an actual YML validation error. Other than that, if the theme is installed/enabled, the paths and filenames are all right, and you've rebuilt Drupal's cache, everything else looks correct

Comment: It wasn't an indentation error in my `libaries.yml` It appeared that a custom module  can't have the same machine name as a custom theme. I figured this out, by uninstalling a custom module (with the same name) and reinstalled the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run into this error after installing a custom theme:

> The specified library "foobar/foobar" does not exist.

"*Drupal\Core\Asset\Exception\InvalidLibrariesExtendSpecificationException: The specified library "foobar/cke-dialog" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Asset\LibraryDiscoveryCollector->applyLibrariesExtend() (line 154 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/LibraryDiscoveryCollector.php).*"

You might have a *custom module* enabled with the same **machinename**

***Solution:***

1. uninstall custom theme/module
2. Rename the **machinename** of custom theme/module